# Можно ли уменьшить ширину в TinyMCE ?

Tags: tinymce

Нужно уменьшить ширину у данного редактора. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

width

> Эта опция дает вам возможность указать ширину редактора в пикселях или в процентах.

Пример использования:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        width : "640"
});
```

Comment: width : "300px", - сделал так но ничего не изменилось...